# python でタイムゾーン変換

Tags: python

python にあまりなれていなくて
今日の JST0時の UTC 時刻
(2019/11/14 15:00:00 が正解)
を取り出したいのですがどうすればいいんでしょうか

```
import datetime

jst = timezone('Asia/Tokyo')
jst_now = datetime.now.replace(jst)
jst_start_today = datetime(jst_now.year, jst_now.month, jst_now.day, 0, 0, 0, jst)
```

のようなことをいろいろ試行錯誤してみてるんですが
メソッドが見つからないばかりで動作すらままなりません

ブログ記事を検索しても datetime が１回だったり２回並べてたり人によって書き方が違うみたいなんですが
バージョンによって書き方が違ったりするんでしょうか

ruby や javascript には begining_of_day みたいなメソッドがあると思うんですが
python にもあったりしませんか？

あと python のメソッドドキュメントってこれでいいんでしょうか
https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/datetime.html

これだとメソッドの検索性が悪くてなかなかやりたいことにたどり着けません

Java API ドキュメントのようにクラスのメソッド一覧をすぐ探す方法はありませんか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

解1

```
import datetime

jst = datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=9))
print("jst =>", jst)

jst_now = datetime.datetime.now(jst)
print("jst_now =>", jst_now)

jst_today = jst_now.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
print("jst_today =>", jst_today)

jst_today_as_utc = jst_today.astimezone(datetime.timezone.utc)
print("jst_today_as_utc =>", jst_today_as_utc)

print(jst_today_as_utc.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

解1の実行結果。

```
jst => UTC+09:00
jst_now => 2019-11-15 17:46:30.304059+09:00
jst_today => 2019-11-15 00:00:00+09:00
jst_today_as_utc => 2019-11-14 15:00:00+00:00
2019/11/14 15:00:00
```

解2。

```
import datetime

jst = datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=9))
print("jst =>", jst)

today = datetime.date.today()
print("today =>", today)

zero = datetime.time()
print("zero =>", zero)

jst_today = datetime.datetime.combine(today, zero, tzinfo=jst)
print("jst_today =>", jst_today)

jst_today_as_utc = jst_today.astimezone(datetime.timezone.utc)
print("jst_today_as_utc =>", jst_today_as_utc)

print(jst_today_as_utc.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

解2の実行結果。

```
jst => UTC+09:00
today => 2019-11-15
zero => 00:00:00
jst_today => 2019-11-15 00:00:00+09:00
jst_today_as_utc => 2019-11-14 15:00:00+00:00
2019/11/14 15:00:00
```

メソッドが見つからないというのはモジュールとモジュールのインポートについて理解できていないためだと思います。datetime モジュールの中に datetime,date,time,timezone といったクラスが定義されていることを理解してください。

Comment: １つ目の datetime がモジュールで２つ目がクラスだったのですね。おっしゃる通り import datetime と from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone と書いた場合で違うことを理解できてなかったです。